# flutter SearchDelegate how to display result without clicking magnifying glass

Tags: android, flutter

i have a listTile storing the query, how can i display search result directly once i click on the listTile?

```
    ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  showSearch(
                    context: context,
                    query: query,
                    delegate: DataSearch(),
                  );
                },
....
              ),
```

now its just a prefilled textfield..i need to click on the button to perform search, how can i skip this step?

[image]

Comment: i want to tap on ListTile and direct to searchResult, textfield is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TextField with onChanged:

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (query) {
    showSearch(
       context: context,
       query: query,
       delegate: DataSearch(),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: i want to tap on ListTile and direct to searchResult, textfield is not relevant.

Comment: i already stored the query and my question is saying the "stored query" only appeared as a prefilled string in the textfield but not directly route to showSearch